# maps not loading markers asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to create a google map with multiple locations. The map comes up fine but the markers do not appear for each latitude and longitude. Not sure what I could be doing wrong here. I found the code online, just tweaked it based on what the requirement was. I would appreciate if you could help me out here.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey&sensor=false"
       type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    // Cretes the map
    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.0046, -93.2140),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        generateMarkers(
    ['Albia', 41.0157, -92.8094],
    ['Algona', 43.0811, -94.2356],
    ['Altoona', 41.6438, -93.4648],
    ['Ames', 42.0225, -93.6689],
    ['Ankeny', 41.7343, -93.6007],
    ['Atlantic', 41.4041, -94.9899],
    ['Bedford', 40.6758, -94.7259],
    ['Bettendorf', 41.5536, -90.4849],
    ['Bloomfield', 41.7514, -92.4189],
    ['Boone', 42.0638, -93.8765],
    ['Burlington', 40.8018, -91.1106],
    ['Carroll', 42.0713, -94.8771],
    ['Cedar Falls', 42.513, -92.4328],
    ['Cedar Rapids', 41.9743, -91.6978],
    ['Centerville', 40.7383, -92.8678],
    ['Chariton', 41.0147, -93.3253],
    ['Charles City', 43.0661, -92.6739],
    ['Cherokee', 42.7641, -95.5521],
    ['Clarinda', 40.7267, -95.0378],
    ['Clinton', 41.8364, -90.1931],
    ['Columbus Junction', 41.2799, 91.3606],
    ['Coralville', 41.6821, -91.592],
    ['Corning', 40.919, -94.7321],
    ['Corydon', 40.7573, -93.3157],
    ['Council Bluffs', 41.2613, -95.879],
    ['Creston', 41.0504, -94.3744],
    ['Davenport', 41.5105, -90.6202],
    ['Denison', 42.0168, -95.3535],
    ['Des Moines', 41.6256, -93.6527],
    ['Dubuque', 42.4915, -90.7251],
    ['Eldora', 42.3608, -93.1034],
    ['Estherville', 43.4021, -94.8286],
    ['Fairfield', 41.0047, -91.9786],
    ['Fort Dodge', 42.5052, -94.1581],
    ['Fort Madison', 40.6268, -91.3424],
    ['Grimes', 41.6868, -93.7826],
    ['Grinnell', 41.7347, -92.7269],
    ['Harlan', 41.6461, -95.3366],
    ['Humboldt', 42.7318, -94.2168],
    ['Huxley', 41.8943, -93.6007],
    ['Indianola', 41.3683, -93.5581],
    ['Iowa City', 41.6433, -91.5308],
    ['Iowa Falls', 42.5087, -93.2618],
    ['Jefferson', 42.0153, -94.375],
    ['Johnston', 41.6648, -93.6991],
    ['Keokuk', 40.4151, -91.4033],
    ['Knoxville', 41.3254, -93.1068],
    ['Lamoni', 40.6239, -93.9248],
    ['Laurens', 42.8468, -94.8516],
    ['Le Mars', 42.7778, -96.1847],
    ['Leon', 40.7397, -93.7565],
    ['Marcus', 42.8248, -95.8079],
    ['Marion', 42.0358, -91.5719],
    ['Marshalltown', 42.0391, -92.9127],
    ['Mason City', 43.1485, -93.2357],
    ['Milford', 43.4325, -95.1498],
    ['Mount Ayr', 40.7117, -94.233],
    ['Mount Pleasant', 40.9606, -91.5225],
    ['Muscatine', 41.4498, -91.0355],
    ['Newton', 41.6991, -93.0339],
    ['Osceola', 41.0304, -93.7723],
    ['Oskaloosa', 41.2949, -92.6497],
    ['Ottumwa', 41.0168, -92.4387],
    ['Pella', 41.3969, -92.9029],
    ['Perry', 41.8288, -94.1037],
    ['Pleasant Hill', 41.5979, -93.5199],
    ['Red Oak', 41.0195, -95.2328],
    ['Sheldon', 43.1866, -95.8314],
    ['Shenandoah', 40.7618, -95.3848],
    ['Sioux Center', 43.0562, -96.1754],
    ['Sioux City', 42.5196, -96.4178],
    ['Spencer', 43.1461, -95.1465],
    ['Spirit Lake', 43.4228, -95.1133],
    ['Storm Lake', 42.6526, -95.2009],
    ['Urbandale', 41.6294, -93.7369],
    ['Wapello', 41.1818, 91.1852],
    ['Washington', 41.2959, -91.7078],
    ['Waterloo', 42.4726, -92.3767],
    ['Waukee', 41.6155, -93.8538],
    ['Waverly', 42.7138, -92.4761],
    ['Webster City', 42.4695, -93.8246],
    ['West Des Moines', 41.597, -93.7522],
    ['Windsor Heights', 41.6004, -93.7151],
    ['Canton', 40.566, -90.0349],
    ['Galesburg', 40.9722, -90.3823],
    ['Hamilton', 40.3932, -91.345],
    ['Macomb', 40.4587, -90.6482],
    ['Milan', 41.4439, -90.5694],
    ['Moline', 41.4899, -90.4769],
    ['Peoria', 40.7394, -89.6058],
    ['Peru', 41.3395, -89.1291],
    ['Quincy', 39.9134, -91.3949],
    ['Rock Island', 41.4933, -90.5586],
    ['Silvis', 41.4897, -90.4216],
    ['Sycamore', 41.9587, -88.7189],
    ['Lawrence', 38.9428, -95.2814],
    ['Leawood', 38.9076, -94.6075],
    ['Lenexa', 38.971, -94.7413],
    ['Manhattan', 39.1859, -96.5609],
    ['Mission', 39.0203, -94.6619],
    ['Olathe', 38.8838, -94.7727],
    ['Overland Park', 38.9564, -94.7199],
    ['Prairie Village', 38.9907, -94.6078],
    ['Shawnee', 39.0148, -94.7432],
    ['Topeka', 39.0144, -95.7621],
    ['Albert Lea', 43.6843, -93.3588],
    ['Austin', 43.68, -92.99],
    ['Fairmont', 43.6455, -94.4474],
    ['Faribault', 44.2952, -93.297],
    ['Mankato', 44.1649, -94.0068],
    ['Marshall', 44.4379, -95.7763],
    ['New Ulm', 44.2929, -94.4411],
    ['Owatonna', 44.0673, -93.2261],
    ['Rochester', 44.0065, -92.4681],
    ['Waseca', 44.0899, -93.5068],
    ['Windom', 43.8671, -95.1144],
    ['Winona', 44.0469, -91.6762],
    ['Worthington', 43.6317, -95.5967],
    ['Albany', 40.2558, -94.3252],
    ['Belton', 38.8137, -94.5208],
    ['Bethany', 40.2586, -94.0279],
    ['Blue Springs', 39.0104, -94.2713],
    ['Chillicothe', 39.7986, -93.5539],
    ['Columbia', 38.9549, -92.3832],
    ['Gladstone', 39.2225, -94.5483],
    ['Grant City', 40.4875, -94.4069],
    ['Independence', 39.0784, -94.3946],
    ['Jefferson City', 38.5859, -92.2559],
    ['Kansas City', 39.2469, -94.6468],
    ['Kirksville', 40.1983, -92.5719],
    ['Lees Summit', 38.9188, -94.36],
    ['Liberty', 39.2453, -94.4495],
    ['Maryville', 40.3337, -94.8736],
    ['Osage Beach', 38.1619, -92.6042],
    ['Princeton', 40.3972, -93.5869],
    ['Raytown', 38.9938, -94.4693],
    ['Springfield', 37.1591, -93.3152],
    ['St. Joseph', 39.7675, -94.8033],
    ['Tarkio', 40.4389, -95.3759],
    ['Trenton', 40.0744, -93.6015],
    ['Unionville', 40.4722, -93.0192],
    ['Columbus', 41.4389, -97.3635],
    ['Fremont', 41.4515, -96.4867],
    ['Grand Island', 40.918, -98.3823],
    ['Lincoln', 40.8135, -96.6511],
    ['Norfolk', 42.0325, -97.4065],
    ['Omaha', 41.2412, -95.9939],
    ['Papillion', 41.1374, -96.0242],
    ['Plattsmouth', 41.0109, -95.9096],
    ['South Sioux City', 42.4659, -96.4277],
    ['Brookings', 44.2972, -96.7689],
    ['Sioux Falls', 43.5317, -96.6716],
    ['Vermillion', 42.7869, -96.9386],
    ['Watertown', 44.8899, -97.0947],
    ['Yankton', 42.8908, -97.3966],
    ['Madison', 43.1188, -89.3204]
  );
    }

    // This function takes an array argument containing a list of marker data
    function generateMarkers(locations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                title: locations[i][0]
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    }
  </script>

</head> 
<body> 
 <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
      initialize();
   };
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an extra set of square braces around your markers to make it a list of lists, currently the locations argument getting passed to generate markers is only the first point.

It should be `[['Albia', 41.0157, -92.8094]...['Madison', 43.1188, -89.3204]]`.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RrQ/)

Comment: Thank you so much Kieran. I was spending a lot of hours trying to figure this out. You saved my evening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
generateMarkers(
    ['Albia', 41.0157, -92.8094],
    ['Algona', 43.0811, -94.2356],
    ...
)
```

substitue it with

```
generateMarkers(
   [
    ['Albia', 41.0157, -92.8094],
    ['Algona', 43.0811, -94.2356],
    ...
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Salvador..yeah Kieran indicated the same problem. Got that fixed. Thanks!!